# runtime conversion of List to HList

Tags: scala, types, shapeless

I want to have a generic list of different types and I want to get objects with specific type.

I have this structure:

```
trait Parent
case class A() extends Parent
case class B() extends Parent
case class C() extends Parent
```

I may define different lists with different size of:

```
val list:List[Parent] = A() :: B() :: C() :: C() ::Nil //or any size or ordering
```

I want to cast this in runtime to Hlist of A,B,C,C. .toHlist[] need types of elements which should be infer in runtime.
What would be Shapeless way of it? Is there any way to convert it to tuples?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: As others have replied, once you go to `List[Parent]` all compile time type information about the individual elements in the list (which is required to create an HList) is gone. It's an irreversible operation.

Comment: @ziggystar I need using something like this: myHlist.filter[A] but because of different runtime flow in my code it could be anything. let say we have a condition so in one branch it could be A::B::C::C in another one could be something completely different, so I don't the type order in compile time, is there any way that in each branch I defined it different? or is there any other way to get the same goal?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it. Note that

> should be infer in runtime

is a contradiction. Type inference works in compile time *only*.

In other words, when you write something like

```
val list: A :: B :: C :: C :: HNil = ...
```

the type of `list` variable is known at *compile time*. It is impossible to assign a type to a variable at runtime, it just doesn't make sense. Suppose it would be possible, and you would have a magical method `toHlistMagical`:

```
val list: List[Parent] = A() :: B() :: C() :: C() :: Nil
val hlist = list.toHlistMagical  // infers to  A :: B :: C :: C :: HNil
```

Now let's change it a bit:

```
def getHlist(list: List[Parent]) = list.toHlistMagical
```

Now what return type do you expect for this function to have? Bear in mind that it can be called with various lists, not only those which contain `A`, `B`, `C`, `C` instances in this order:

```
getHlist(C() :: B() :: A() :: A() :: Nil)
```

It could be `Any`, but then you can just go with `List` anyway because there is no `HList` anymore, so you don't get any extra type safety.

That's the reason why `toHlist` needs types:

```
def getHlist(list: List[Parent]) = list.toHlist[A :: B :: C :: C :: HNil]
```

`getHlist` now has return type `Option[A :: B :: C :: C :: HNil]`, because you specified the exact type you want, and `toHlist` will be able to perform runtime validation of the `list` structure and return `Some` if the list does actually contain these types in this order or `None` if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

The following function can convert your list to a HList:

```
def listToHList(x: List[_]): HList = {
  if(x == Nil) HNil
  else x.head :: listToHList(x.tail)
}
```

For your sample, you can use it like the following:

`listToHList(list).asInstanceOf[A :: B :: C :: HNil]`